# SQL Server 2005 - RIGHT() not working when adding to CHARINDEX()

Tags: sql-server-2005, charindex

I'm trying to use the `RIGHT` function to get the substring of a value if it consists of a '/', but it doesn't work when I add a number to the `CHARINDEX` value; only without.

Here is a sample of the code:

```
SELECT CASE
            WHEN 
                CHARINDEX('/',REPLACE(ISNULL(d.target_grade,'NA'), 'N/A', 'NA')) = 0
            THEN 
                REPLACE(ISNULL(d.target_grade,'NA'),'N/A','NA')
            ELSE 
                RIGHT(d.target_grade, CHARINDEX('/',REPLACE(ISNULL(d.target_grade,'NA'), 'N/A', 'NA'))+1)
        END as target_grade
FROM tbl --etc.
```

This returns for example

```
target_grade
-------------
C/D
```

It should return though this

```
target_grade
-------------
D
```

If I remove the `+1`, however, the `RIGHT` function works exactly as it should

```
target_grade
-------------
/D
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is my logic flawed?

Comment: Your logic is wrong - `charindex` counts from the **left** of the string,but `right` counts from the **right** of the string...

Comment: All answers correct, chose @PhilipKelley for pointing out extra considerations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend avoiding overly-complex string manipulations by leveraging the power of the `CASE` statement. Try something like this:

```
CASE
  when d.target_grade is null then 'NA'
  when d.target_grade = 'N/A' then 'NA'
  when charindex('/', d.target_grade) = 0 then d.target_grade
  else substring(d.target_grade, charindex('/', d.target_grade) + 1, XX)  --  Replace XX with the max posssible length of d.target_grade
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Since [`RIGHT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177532.aspx) wants "how many characters to keep" rather than "where to start the string from", your current logic is wrong.

Simpler, if you already have "where to start the string from" is to use [`SUBSTRING`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx):

```
SELECT CASE
            WHEN 
                CHARINDEX('/',REPLACE(ISNULL(d.target_grade,'NA'), 'N/A', 'NA')) = 0
            THEN 
                REPLACE(ISNULL(d.target_grade,'NA'),'N/A','NA')
            ELSE 
                SUBSTRING(d.target_grade, 
                         CHARINDEX('/',REPLACE(ISNULL(d.target_grade,'NA'), 'N/A', 'NA'))+1
                          ,8000)
        END as target_grade
FROM tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

Silly me, like @MarkBannister said, `charindex` counts from the **left** of the string, but `right` counts from the **right** of the string. Therefore the above should be

```
SELECT CASE
            WHEN 
                CHARINDEX('/',REPLACE(ISNULL(d.target_grade,'NA'), 'N/A', 'NA')) = 0
            THEN 
                REPLACE(ISNULL(d.target_grade,'NA'),'N/A','NA')
            ELSE
                -- Use -1 NOT 1 
                RIGHT(d.target_grade, CHARINDEX('/',REPLACE(ISNULL(d.target_grade,'NA'), 'N/A', 'NA'))-1)
        END as target_grade
FROM tbl --etc.
```

`-1` NOT `+1`

Comment: That's only correct if you happen to know that the slash appears in exactly the centre of the string. This logic would still be incorrect if you expect `ABC/D` to return `D` (where your version will return `C/D`). If you're insistent on using `RIGHT` rather than `SUBSTRING`, the correct thing to do would be to subtract the `CHARINDEX` result from `LEN`.